# How to prevent unnecessary scrolling in diagram?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have the following diagram with overview:

```
var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
var diagram =
      $(go.Diagram, element[0],{
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
            initialScale: (pageBodyWidth > 500 ? 1 : 0.6),
            contentAlignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
            layout: $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout, { direction: 0 }),
            isReadOnly: false,
            allowLink: true,
            allowClipboard: false,
            'animationManager.duration': 200,
            'undoManager.isEnabled': false
      });
var overview = $(go.Overview, 'diagramOverview', { observed: diagram });
```

After this I see a diagram but there is unnecessary scrolling and it exists on overview:
[image]

How to disable this scrolling? I want to have a fixed diagram area.

Also I see that diagram has an extra space:
[image]

What is this space? Is it possible to have a diagram without this space as in example here http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartStatic.html ?

Comment: How does one reproduce this behavior?  I modified the Org Chart (static) sample to give the Overview 200px height and 100px width (like your screenshot), and I was unable to scroll the Diagram's viewport in the Overview beyond the document bounds of the Diagram.
BTW, you'd probably get a faster response if you used our forum: https://forum.nwoods.com/c/gojs

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "allowHorizontalScroll: false" and "allowVerticalScroll: false" when you define the diagram so it will become:

    `var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    var diagram =
      $(go.Diagram, element[0],{
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
            initialScale: (pageBodyWidth > 500 ? 1 : 0.6),
            contentAlignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
            layout: $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout, { direction: 0 }),
            isReadOnly: false,
            allowLink: true,
            allowClipboard: false,
            'animationManager.duration': 200,
            'undoManager.isEnabled': false,
             allowHorizontalScroll: false,
             allowVerticalScroll: false
      });
    var overview = $(go.Overview, 'diagramOverview', { observed: diagram });`